# I am not getting the display of images when i run my jsp page.why?

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, http-headers

the error i got in browser is:"Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html"....please help me what to do now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please set MIME type to `image/jpg` or appropriate or image

your image should be sent with header `Content-type: image/png` or appropriate